# Can't access Sites folder localhost/username/Sites not working El Capitan

Tags: installation, apache-http-server, osx-el-capitan, username

```
httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Unix)
Server built:   Feb 20 2016 20:03:19
Mac OS El Capitan 10.11.6
```

I hope I am not violating rules by reposting my question I have written on stackexhange. If this is incorrect, please, let me know.
I have troubles accessing my Sites folder. I am a newbie, and I am at my wit's end because I have studied all possible links (the ones I am capable to understand) and have performed all necessary changes, but `localhost/username/Sites` keeps telling me:

```
Not Found
The requested URL /~username/Sites was not found on this server.
```

I have tried also:

```
Not Found
The requested URL /username/Sites was not found on this server.
```

Of course I use my name instead of username. I have added lines to username.conf as per 
https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/forbidden-403-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-username-on-this-server/
and 
https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-working-on-osx-10-11-el-capitan/

Here is the link to my original post
[https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/264174/apache-localhost-doesnt-work-safari-cant-connect-to-the-server-localhost](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/264174/apache-localhost-doesnt-work-safari-cant-connect-to-the-server-localhost%20Can't%20connect%20to%20localhost)

I will be grateful for help. I truly need to fix this issue and get the thing running.

Answer (score 0):

When you have Apache enabled,
the *content* of your `~/Sites` directory becomes visible at `http://localhost/~youruser`.
In other words, instead of `/~username/Sites`, you're really looking for `/~username`.

Try this for a simple test:

```
echo hello > ~/Sites/hello.html
```

And visit in your browser `http://localhost/~youruser/hello.html`.

If Apache is correctly setup, you should see a primitive page with just "hello" on it.

Comment: When opening localhost/~username I should see a list of directories, etc, very basic page, but I don't see it. I have a few folders in my Sites folders, but I don't see contents of any of those:

Comment: I can access, for example: `localhost/~username/Sites/folder/somefile.php`  or `localhost/~username/Sites/another_folder/somefile.html`

Comment: So you can access specific files, but your question is how to see directory listings?

Comment: No, sorry it was a typo - I *can't* access any of those files. Sorry for this typo.

Comment: Can you access `hello.html` if you perform simple sanity test I suggested?

Comment: I couldn't, but I have realized that I have not created the file. Now I have hello.html in the Sites folder with content `<html>
<header><title>This is title</title></header>
<body>
Hello world
</body>
</html>` When I try to browse `http://localhost/~myname/hello.html` , I see this whole code, not just Hello world phrase.

Comment: And I actually browse the page using 192..../~myname/hello.html; if I simply type localhost (literally `localhost`) I get "can't find the file" response from the browser.